# Nodejs, read from /dev/input/event* right way

Tags: node.js, events, input

I have code like this and have strange effect, 
if there are more then 3 devices opened,
it doesnt work properly.

i have the same functional in python with select polling
and it works good.

please say "where is my BAD ?"

```
var fs = require("fs"),
  path = require("path");

function is_device(device_path) {
        return (
            device_path.indexOf("event") >= 0 && 
            fs.statSync(device_path).isCharacterDevice()
        );
    }

    function list_devices(base_dir) {
        return fs.readdirSync(base_dir).map(function(device){
            return path.join(base_dir, device);
        }).filter(is_device);
    }


    var chunks = [];


    function read_devices(base_dir) {
        // if we slice return of list_devices to 3
        // it will be work good and many dots we can see....
        var devices =  list_devices(base_dir).map(function(device_name){
            try {
                return fs.createReadStream(device_name, {
                    flags: 'r',
                    encoding: null
                })
                .on('readable', function(){
                    this.read(16);
                    process.stdout.write('.');
                });
            } catch(e){
                return null;
            }
        });
        return devices.filter(function(device){return device != null;});
    }

    var device_streams = read_devices("/dev/input/");
```